# bash prinf goes to log but output= not

Tags: macos, bash

The first line of this snipet goes to the logfile, but the second doesn't.
I need the second be executed and loged.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s %s (%s) running...\n' 2>&1 | tee -a $logfile
output=$(restic -r ${backupdir} snapshots ) 2>&1 | tee -a $logfile
```

How can i log the output= line as well?

Comment: The second line basically tries to add the output of an assignment statement to the log file. As this statement doesn't produce any output there is nothing to add :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second line, there should be no output! You're assigning the result of `restic -r ${backupdir} snapshots` to `output`, and that won't produce any output, either to `stdout` or to `stderr` (it's equivalent to `output="Value stored for later"` - when this command executes, there's no output).

Try something like...

```
output=$(restic -r ${backupdir} snapshots )
echo $output | tee -a $logfile
```

Or you could simplify it by just doing...

```
restic -r ${backupdir} snapshots 2>&1 | tee -a $logfile
```